# Hiddenfield value always shows 0 in Server Side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here I set values to hidden field but when I access it from server side it always shows 0

```
<input type="hidden" ID="hdnSelectedChurch" runat="server" value="0" />

 $('select').change(function () {
        var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        var valueSelected = optionSelected.val(); <-- Selected value correct here.
        //var x = $('#SelectedChurch').val($(this).val());
        var hdnSelectedChurch = ($(this).val());
        LoadFathersToChurch(valueSelected);

    });
```

access in Server Side

```
protected void btnSubmitChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       int Church = Convert.ToInt32(hdnSelectedChurch.Value);
       // int Churchstr =Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[hdnSelectedChurch.UniqueID]);
  }
```

Comment: Where are you setting the value of the hidden field? e.g. where is `$('#clientidoffield').val(somevalue)`

Comment: Where are you setting the field's value, and how is it being sent to the server?

Comment: I use this  var hdnSelectedChurch = ($(this).val()); Can't i ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**Control.ClientID**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the client id of control, then use [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set its value

```
var hdnSelectedChurch = '<%# hdnSelectedChurch.ClientID %>';   
$('#' + hdnSelectedChurch).val($(this).val());
```

instead of

```
var hdnSelectedChurch = ($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to set the value of the hidden field (which I don't see you doing):

```
$('select').change(function () {
   // other stuff here ...
   $("input[id*=hdnSelectedChurch").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: It's a `RUNAT="server"`... the id is not #hdnSelectedChurch on the client (made the same initial mistake myself)/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yep, you're right, I forgot that the the client Id would be prefixed. I've edited.

Comment: Good simple fix (for the uninformed this simply relies on the fact that the ID is suffixed with the original ID when the client ID is generated) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Well It does, doesn't it ? My WebForms skills are a bit rusty :)

Comment: Reworded comment... it was meant to be an explanation :)